# If() operator inside if statement (possible bug)

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, if-statement

I just came across a weird problem (*bug?*)

I am trying to initialize a variable inside an `if` statement in razor and i want it to have a value depending on a condition so i am also using an the inline `if()` operator.

The minimal buggy example is

```
@If true Then
    Dim ajaxurl As String = If(True, "a value", "another value")
End If
```

This simple code will yield

> The "**If**" block was not terminated. All "**If**" statements must be terminated with a matching "**End If**".

Of course my real usage is more complex (*deeper nesting of `if` statemens and a lot more going inside them*), so just using the inline `if()` directly where i want to put the `ajaxurl` will not solve the problem..

I know I could use `IIf()` instead of `if()` but still.. is there an explanation for this ?

---

***Note:*** using the `if()` operator when outside the code block works..

so

```
@If true Then
    @<span>@(If(True, "a value", "another value"))</span>
End If
```

works just fine..

---

*Updating with a more real example just to showcase the complexity*

```
@If Model.Count > 0 Then
    For Each item In Model
    @<li>
        @If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ArchivedObjectTitle) Then
            @<span class="label">@Html.CulturalText("ΣΥΝΔΕΕΤΑΙ ΜΕ", "LINKED WITH"):</span>@<br />
            If routeData("action").tolower <> "accompanying-directory" Then

                Dim directUrl As String
                Dim ajaxUrl As String = String.Empty

                If (Not Tools.IsGeophysical(item.ArchivedObjectType)) AndAlso item.ArchivedObjectType = ArchivedObjectsENUM.REGION Then
                    directUrl = Url.Action("region", New With {.id = item.ArchivedObjectID})
                    ajaxUrl = Url.Action("Archived-Item", New With {.id = item.ArchivedObjectID})
                Else
' ********************************************** '
' The following line which contains the If() cause the  '
' the first @If Model.Count > 0 Then to fail in parsing '
                    directUrl = Url.Action(If(Tools.IsGeophysical(item.ArchivedObjectType), "Geophysical-Item", "Archived-Item"), New With {.id = item.ArchivedObjectID})
                End If

                @<strong><a class="ajaxify" href="@directUrl" @Html.HtmlAttribute("data-url", ajaxUrl, ajaxUrl <> String.Empty)>@item.ArchivedObjectTitle</a></strong>@<br />
            Else
                @<strong>@item.ArchivedObjectTitle</strong>@<br />
            End If
        End If

        @If item.HasMore Then
            @<a href="@Url.Action("Accompanying-Item", New With {.id = item.AccompanyingObjectID})" class="ajaxify more-info" data-title="@item.Title">&nbsp;</a>
        End If
    </li>
    Next
Else
    ...
End if
```

Comment: Note: That is the If *Operator* not the If Statement/function. Also note `IIf` is deprecated so should not be used (it is not type safe). This doesn't help you I know but there is an important difference between the two.

Comment: The `If condition Then` is the `If` statement.. the function is indeed the operator..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this sort of thing appears in your Views a lot, I would suggest that you create an HTML Helper to deal with it (as opposed to having all of that VB code in Razor).  I would imagine that you will not see this same buggy behavior if you move all of that VB conditional logic outside of Razor.

The explanation for the behavior you are seeing is that Razor was not written with VB in mind (and vice-versa).

The result is that your Razor Views end up looking ridiculous.  For example:

```
@If True Then
    @Code
        Dim ajaxurl As String = (If(True, "a value", "another value"))
    End Code                      
End If
```

It isn't the most elegant solution, but it should solve your problem.  Your other choice is to not use the ternary conditional operator, and just start using regular `If` statements.

```
@If True Then
    Dim ajaxurl As String
    If True Then
        ajaxurl = "a value"
    Else
        ajaxurl = "another value"
    End If
End If
```

Again, far from the most elegant code you could be writing, but then again, VB is probably not the best language choice if you are really worried about that sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

Since your if contains only code blocks try wrapping it in a code block:

```
@Code
    If True Then
        Dim ajaxurl As String = If(True, "a value", "another value")
    End If
End Code
```

Comment: I wish it was just an intellisense error.. but i get a runtime "Parser Error" as well.. Also not using `<script>` tags at all..

Comment: it does not in my real usage.. i just posted a simplified example to demonstrate the problem..

Comment: i do know how to work around it with a few ways, but was really trying to understand if it is something i am doing wrong or if it is indeed a bug..